# VBA: Variable alias

Tags: vba, excel, class, ms-word

**Re-framed the question:** I used a range (which contains the headers) to define an array, which I initialized and extracted the data from a table. Things went well (with redundant and repeated code), but I could directly write the array to an Excel row.

But the code required validation and initialization, hence I migrated to a class which encapsulates both requirements. The dynamic implementation required re-writing the class with `InsertLines`.

The problem is, now I have the data in a class, but I'm at a loss how to write it to a single row.

**Previous algorithm:**

```
Dim MyRange as Range
Dim sTR() as string

'set myrange to a specific range of cells'
'Redim the sTR array to match the number of unique variables in the range
'Extract values from multiples rows in a table to the sTR array'
'Write the array to the Excel file with:' 
MyRange.Offset(x, y).value = sTR()
```

**Current way:**

```
Dim MyRange as Range

'set myrange to a specific range of cells (Nine columns and variable rows)'
'InsertCode into a class module with all unique values in the range as public variables
Dim sTR as ClassX
Set sTR as New ClassX

'Extract values from multiples rows in a table to the sTR Class'
```

Now the problem is, I have no idea about the order of the variables in the class (this was not an issue with the previous method with array, but that way certainly involves too much code redundancy).

Help please! Wanted to know if a variable can be addressed by different names (alias), which would solve my problem. Or is there a way to address all public variables in a class (say with a loop)?

Comment: I'd be glad to provide an example if something is not clear

Comment: it is always better to see the code of better understanding or/and before/after result screen shots. But please limit your code only to that what is most important and will help to understand your needs better...

Comment: Writing dynamic code based on the content of your data is often a design approach which can be better handled using something like a Dictionary object: ie. you just need a string based "key" into the data.

Comment: Re-framed the question with theoretical code. Can a dictionary object be used in a class?

Comment: Your theoretical code doesn't offer enough detail to figure out what a good approach might be, but yes you can use a dictionary object in a class. You could for example use a Dictionary to store the index to each column "name" so that you could recall a specific value by passing the column header to your class.